# Translating Linq to a FSharp expression

Tags: linq, f#

The DocumentDB has a walk-though and sample project in C# that I am working through in FSharp.  One of the 1st tasks is to locate an existing datbase.  The C# code is this

```cs
var database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(db => db.Id == "FamilyRegistry").ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
```

I am attempting to do the same line in FSharp but I am not getting the .Where even though I am referencing the same libraries.  Instead I am getting this:

[image]

Am I thinking about the problem wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add a reference to `System.Linq` ? LINQ isn't C# specific. Even in C# you need to add a reference to `System.Linq.dll` and a `using System.Linq;` statement

Comment: That was it.  I added a reference to Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq only -> so I referenced the extension methods but not the core.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to make this more F# idomatic? let database = client.CreateDatabaseQuery().Where(fun db -> db.Id = "FamilyRegistry" ).ToArray().FirstOrDefault()

Comment: Why is there a `.ToArray()` call in the C# code? Does that serve an actual purpose, or is it just there to waste time?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Linq isn't specific to C#. Even in C# you need to add a reference to `System.Linq.dll` and a `using System.Linq;` statement. The C# project templates already include these statements.

In F# you need to do the same, ensure your project has a reference to System.Linq and add an `open System.Linq` statement

There are at least two more idiomatic ways:

1. You can use the Seq module's functions with the pipeline operator achieve the same result as method chaining,  eg:

   ```
   let random = new System.Random()
   Seq.initInfinite (fun _ -> random.Next())
   |> Seq.filter (fun x -> x % 2 = 0)
   |> Seq.take 5
   |> Seq.iter (fun elem -> printf "%d " elem)
   printfn ""
   ```

   `seq<'T>` is a synonym of `IEnumerable<T>` so if you apply the methods to an IQueryable it will force the query's execution.
2. You can use [Query Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh225374.aspx), equivalent to LINQ's SQL-like syntax:

   ```
   let countOfStudents =
       query {
           for student in db.Student do
           select student
           count
       }
   ```

   `query` returns a proper `IQueryable<T>`

Your specific query could be something like this:

```
let database =  
    query {
        for db in client.CreateDatabaseQuery()
        where db.Id == "FamilyRegistry"
        select db
        headOrDefault
    }
```